# Issue while creating an application through okta api

Tags: okta, okta-api

I am facing issues while creating an Okta app via Okta APIs.

I followed [this documentation](https://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/apps) to create an app with  the following:

```
headers = {
  'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'SSWS '+api_token,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

input = {"name": tenant_name, "label": "Sample tenant App", "signOnMode": "OPENID_CONNECT",   
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=input)
url: https://dev-231233.oktapreview.com/api/v1/apps (example)
```

But I am getting following error:

```
{'errorCode': 'E0000007', 'errorSummary': 'Not found: Resource not found: test-tenant (App)', 'errorLink': 'E0000007', 'errorId': 'oaedyrTOkwESTSg7_A8nXrCxg', 'errorCauses': []}
```

I am wondering that I am trying to create an app and this API call is trying to find that app, is anything missing in the request params?

I also tried the python SDK https://github.com/okta/okta-sdk-python but I am getting errors wrt python 3.7 . Looks like it is not maintained recently.

I would appreciate any help with code samples to create an APP using Okta APIs?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the `name` field is NOT a display value, it is a key for the type of application: https://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/apps#app-names--settings

Use `label` for your human-readable value.

Comment: Thanks @Brian Demers for your answer. I tried: input =                                   
 {"name": "template_basic_auth", "label": "Test Web", "signOnMode": "OPENID_CONNECT", "settings": { "app": { "requestIntegration": False, "url": "localhost:8080/";, "authURL": "localhost:8080"; } } } . but get an error .                        { [{'errorSummary': 'Cannot create application instance. Maximum number of instances has been reached.'}]}.      However I am able to create an app from the GUI, any restrictions on API side? What is the reason for this error

Comment: Here is the complete error:                                                                                               {'errorCode': 'E0000001', 'errorSummary': 'Api validation failed: generalSettings', 'errorLink': 'E0000001', 'errorId': 'oae2hOfNjfcTGqUdY1ngXpmLQ', 'errorCauses': [{'errorSummary': 'Cannot create application instance. Maximum number of instances has been reached.'}]}

Comment: IIRC, you get five free, if you delete one does the API allow you to create another?

Comment: I have a paid account. Do you have code samples available somewhere?

Comment: Take a look at our Postman collections: https://developer.okta.com/reference/postman_collections/

Comment: Thanks. I already tried that but get the same error:   {
    "errorCode": "E0000001",
    "errorSummary": "Api validation failed: generalSettings",
    "errorLink": "E0000001",
    "errorId": "oaeMpcUyrB-QDOXnt1fxiKOBg",
    "errorCauses": [
        {
            "errorSummary": "Cannot create application instance. Maximum number of instances has been reached."
        }
    ]
} QUESTION: Does Okta has some issues in creating applications via API from python code? Can you please confirm?

Comment: The client language wouldn't matter.  Can you update the post with the message body you are using? I'll try it out.

Comment: Thanks @Brian Demers. I am able to create apps via python code. The main culprit was the label field and on some dev accounts I was not able to call APIs using a token. this is resolved now.